# MenuItem inside/Sub of another MenuItem in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

How to add a `menuItem` inside/sub of another `menuItem` in Java? is it possible ?

Comment: Did you read [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)?

Comment: oh can I have a menu inside a menu?? didn't know that. I've been searching for the keywords menuItem and nothing shows up in google that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
submenu1 = new JMenu("my submenu");
JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("submenu items");

submenu1.add(menuItem1);

menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("item1");
submenu1.add(menuItem1);
```

[Refer to this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details.

Comment: just tried it. I was adding a JMenuItem inside a JMenuItem and the menu directly crashes. I didn't know you can add JMenu inside a JMenu.  Thanks :)

Comment: look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/MenuLookDemoProject/src/components/MenuLookDemo.java here is a full programm

Answer (score 4):

Add `JMenu` instead of the first `JMenuItem`.

Comment: checking @Howard link. I think I missed something in Menus GUI.